# Can Data Frames Contain Different Classes of Vectors by Rows Instead of Columns in R?

Tags: r

Data frames in R can contain columns of different classes. For example:

```
df <- data.frame(A = LETTERS[1:5], B = rnorm(5, 5, 5), C = 1:5)
> str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ A: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ B: num  11.66 18.74 2.39 6.25 -6.83
 $ C: int  1 2 3 4 5
```

Column `A` is of class `Factor`, column `B` is of class `numeric`, and colun `C` is of class `integer`.

If I transpose this data frame, is it possible to maintain the original `class` classifications? R would have to classify vectors of data by rows instead of by columns.

```
> (new_df <- as.data.frame(t(df)))
         V1        V2        V3        V4        V5
A         A         B         C         D         E
B 11.662710 18.741777  2.388307  6.251556 -6.833578
C         1         2         3         4         5
> class(new_df$V1)
[1] "factor"
> class(new_df["A", ])
[1] "data.frame"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not without redefining a new class of a data frame. What is the motivation behind the question?  Transposing a data frame doesn't actually change any of the data. If we know what it is you are wanting to do, we might be able to offer useful solutions.

Comment: I'm just curious - I don't have an underlying reason. Thanks for the response.